# Can't find info.php on Mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

I have enabled everything following the tutorial on the PHP website for Mac using bundled PHP and others tutorials as well. When I go to http://localhost it displays "it works" but when I go to http://Users/Eric/Sites/info.php I get the error message "The requested URL xxx was not found on this server". I can navigate to Users/Eric/Sites/info.php manually and open it but I can't find it in the browser. If someone could help me figure this out I would appreciate it.

Comment: `Users` is a folder on your machine, not a DNS name, right? Well that's the answer then.

Comment: Yes. What do you mean? There was a typo on the link that has since been corrected.

Comment: You can only use `localhost` (or your IP Address) unless you have your ip address registered to a DNS name like externally users.com or internally to some computer name on your network in an intranet setting. I highly doubt that is the case here. `User` is a folder not a DNS name. Lookup DNS on Wikipedia or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can view files on your local machine in your browser like file:///Users/Eric/Sites/info.php, but that will just give you the source code of that file. It will not execute any of your code. 
If you want to execute your code with http:// you will have to go through your server like http://localhost/info.php  (URL's need to be relative to your root directory, which is localhost)

Example: if you are in your localhost directory that is names test and in that test folder you have a file named test.php you can access it in your browser like: http://localhost/test/test.php

Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, but the issue is that if I go to http://localhost/info.php it's not found. If i go to http://localhost/Users/Eric/Sites/info.php it's not found. If I go to http://localhost/~Eric/info.php it's not found. I don't understand why I can't find it using any of these links since all the tutorials I have followed have been able to. I even updated the permission of my sites file as per this tutorial http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-install-apache-and-php-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-1/

Comment: So is the "It Works" file index.html? Is that what is in your localhost folder? if that file displays and a info.php in the same directory does not display when you go to http://localhost/info.php then there is something configured wrong with your php. On my mac I always downloaded and configured everything all at once using MAMP: http://www.mamp.info/en/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the built-in stuff in a long time, but it's quite possible your tutorials are out-of-date. Things change over time. [here's one](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083) that was updated this year. There is definitely stuff about Yosemite in it, so perhaps it has the steps you need.